# Do you know any good books or pdfs to learn networking and how it works?

Tags: sockets, unix, networking, network-programming

I am looking for book or pdf to learn networking and how it works completely for beginners and making a good introduce to advanced topics.

All what I found was pdfs about networking in some language, but it is not what I am looking for.

Additionally, I will be grateful for some materials to learn networking in UNIX systems.

Answer (score 0):

I found one and it looks pretty good.

http://intronetworks.cs.luc.edu/current/ComputerNetworks.pdf